# sum the second to the last on java

Tags: java, sum

How can I print the sum of the 2nd to the last digit of each integer on java?

(so, 8 would be printed since 1 + 3 + 4 is 8 , and 35 would be printed since 3453 + 65324 + 354) in the following Program: *** without using if statements ***

```
import java.util.*;
public class Pr6{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      int sumSecToLast;

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num1 = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num2 = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num3 = scan.nextInt();

      sumSecToLast = (num1/10) % 10 + (num2/10) % 10 + (num3/10) % 10;
          System.out.print((num1/10) % 10 + " + " + (num2/10) % 10 + " + " + (num3/10) % 10 + " = " + sumSecToLast);


      }//main
}//Pr6
```

Comment: *"35 would be printed since 3453 + 65324 + 354"* - why? Also what isnt working about your code?

Comment: cause the 2nd digit of 3453 is 4, and the sum of the 2nd to the last is 4 + 5 + 3 = 12 for the fist integer. Therefore, if you sum the rest integers with the same way it will be 35.

Comment: (may be wrong) but I think when he means is that (3453 + 65324 + 354) = (4 + 5 + 3) + (5 + 3 + 2 + 4) + (5 + 4) = 35

Comment: @ug_ my program doesn't print 8 when I insert 1 + 3 + 4. it prints 0 instead. also, it just sum the digit next to the last not the whole digits after the second. for ex: (3453 + 65324 + 354) = 5 + 2 + 5 = 12

Comment: I get the strong feeling this is homework. So instead I will give a good hint. `(int) (Math.log(number) / Math.log(10));` - this will give you the number of digits you need to look at. Also write a method that does the sum for a digit. You will also need at least 1 loop in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for inconvenience. My question was misunderstood. I meant that I want to write a code to find the sum of the 2nd to the last digit of a three different integers. For ex: if the user entered 15,  34, and 941, which in this case the 2nd to the last digit will be 1, 3, and 4. Therefore, the subtotal of them will be 1+3+4 = 8.

I found out the answer and I wanted to share it with everyone, and also I would like to thank all of those who tried to help.
thank you..

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Pr6{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int sumSecToLast;
    
    System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
    num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
    num2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
    num3 = scan.nextInt();
    
    sumSecToLast = ((num1/10) % 10) + ((num2/10) % 10) + ((num3/10) % 10);
    System.out.println("The subtotal of the 2nd to the last digit = " + sumSecToLast);
    System.out.println();
    
  }//main
}//Pr6
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've scanned all the integers:

```
//In main method:
int secLast1 = Pr6.getSecLastDigit(num1);
int secLast2 = Pr6.getSecLastDigit(num2);
int secLast3 = Pr6.getSecLastDigit(num3);

int sum = secLast1 + secLast2 + secLast3;
System.out.println(secLast1 + " + " + secLast2 + " + " + secLast3 + " = " + sum);
```

You also want to create the additional method:

```
private static int getSecLastDigit(int num) {
    return (num / 10) % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. Depending on your definition of an `if` statement this might not work for you (spoiler).

```
import java.util.*;
public class Pr6{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int total = 0;
        String num1, num2, num3;

        System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
        num1 = scan.nextLine(); // rather than taking an integer this takes a String because it is easier to extract a single element.

        ... // get the other numbers

        for (int i = 1; i < num1.length(); i++){
            total += Character.getNumericValue(num1.charAt(i)); // adds each number to the total
        }

        ... // do this for the other Strings (or use another loop for with a String[])

        System.out.println(total);
    }//main
}//Pr6
```

To make this more concise I would **highly** recommend using a `String[]` rather than 3 different variables. Also I am assuming a `for` loop doesn't count as an `if` statement. However I realize that because of the `boolean` check they may be considered too similar for your current situation. I hope this helps! :)