# How can I sum the second digit to the last digit in an integer on java?

Tags: java, sum

Can you tell me how Can I fix this program to make the "sumSecTolastD" operator does the following:
*1-* sum the second digit to the last digit in an integer (for example: 324 + 564 + 9876 = 29 since (2 + 4) + (6 + 4) + (8 + 7 + 6) = 29).
*2-* if I insert one digit only, it still able to give me the sum ( for example: 1 + 3 + 4 = 8).

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Pr66{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      int sumLastD;
      int sumSecTolastD;

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num1 = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num2 = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
         num3 = scan.nextInt();

      sumLastD = num1 % 10 + num2 % 10 + num3 % 10;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("- LastDigitSum: " + num1 % 10 + " + " + num2 % 10 + " + " + num3 % 10 + " = " + sumLastD);
        
      if (sumLastD % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println("- LastDigitSum: is an even integer");
      else
        System.out.println("- LastDigitSum: is an odd integer");

        System.out.println();

      sumSecTolastD = (num1/10) % 10 + (num2/10) % 10 + (num3/10) % 10;
        System.out.println("- SecToLastSum: " + (num1/10) % 10 + " + " + (num2/10) % 10 + " + " + (num3/10) % 10 + " = " + sumSecTolastD);
                
      if (sumSecTolastD % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println("- SecToLastSum: is an even integer");
      else
       System.out.println("- SecToLastSum: is an odd integer");
       
        }//main
}//Pr66
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sum the second to the last on java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599609/sum-the-second-to-the-last-on-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for inconvenience. My question was misunderstood. I meant that I want to write a code to find the sum of the 2nd to the last digit of a three different integers. For ex: if the user entered 15, 34, and 941, which in this case the 2nd to the last digit will be 1, 3, and 4. Therefore, the subtotal of them will be 1+3+4 = 8.

I found out the answer and I wanted to share it with everyone, and also I would like to thank all of those who tried to help. thank you..

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Pr6{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int sumSecToLast;
    
    System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
    num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
    num2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please write an integer: ");
    num3 = scan.nextInt();
    
    sumSecToLast = ((num1/10) % 10) + ((num2/10) % 10) + ((num3/10) % 10);
    System.out.println("The subtotal of the 2nd to the last digit = " + sumSecToLast);
    
    if (sumSecToLast % 2 == 0)
      System.out.println(sumSecToLast + " is an even number.");
    else
      System.out.println(sumSecToLast + " is an odd number.");
    
  }//main
}//Pr6
```

Answer (score 0):

This sums only the second to last digits :

```
  sumSecTolastD = (num1/10) % 10 + (num2/10) % 10 + (num3/10) % 10;
```

To sums both second to last and last digits, change it to :

```
  sumSecTolastD = num1%10 + (num1/10) % 10 + num2%10  + (num2/10) % 10 + num3%10 + (num3/10) % 10;
```

The same code would work even if any/all of your input numbers have a single digit, since in that case `(numi/10) % 10` would be `0`, and won't affect the sum.

Answer (score 0):

This sums the last digits:

```
sumLastD = num1 % 10 + num2 % 10 + num3 % 10;
```

To get the sum of the last and second to last, add the result of the above to your calculation for the second to last digits:

```
sumSecTolastD = (num1/10) % 10 + (num2/10) % 10 + (num3/10) % 10 + sumLastD;
```

To make it work with only single digit numbers as well will require additional checks, and make your code much bigger:

```
sumLastD = (String.valueOf(num1).length() > 1 ? num1 % 10 : num1) +
(String.valueOf(num2).length() > 1 ? num2 % 10 : num2) +
(String.valueOf(num3).length() > 1 ? num3 % 10 : num3);
```

Yes, you can put it onto multiple lines, the compiler ignores unnecessary whitespace.

For the `sumSecTolastD` modify the above to:

```
sumSecTolastD = (String.valueOf(num1).length() > 2 ? (num1/10) % 10 : num1) +
(String.valueOf(num2).length() > 2 ? (num2/10) % 10 : num2) +
(String.valueOf(num3).length() > 2 ? (num3/10) % 10 : num3) + sumLastD;
```